# Как убрать не нужную часть полученных данных из формы

Tags: php

При отправке формы при нажатии на Enter - Добавляется новая строка которая фиксируется как

```
___
```

Форма приходит с данными:

```
раз два три __
```

Как с помощью php - удалить этот __ и записать в бд только "раз два три"?

Comment: форма приходит в json*

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'раз два три __';
$trimedStr = trim($str, "_");
echo $trimedStr;  // раз два три
```

**[trim](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php)** - для удаления разных символов с начала и конца строки